# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <button class="button" > is not clickable at point (x,y)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I'm trying to click a button from a [modal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FevBc.png), but when it's the time to click on it, i have the next error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <button onclick="Activar(193);" class="button mx-1" title="Recover">...</button> is not clickable at point (1206, 319). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1349px; height: 613px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
```

I know that i need to use a wait helper, but i don't know exactly how to use it, this is my code with the wait helper:

```
 public ConfigurationUsuario HabilitarConfiguracion()
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            iconoActivar.Click();
            driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@title='Recover']"))).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@title='Recover']")).Click();
            return new ConfigurationUsuario(driver);
        }
```

Probably it's because i don't know how use wait helper, but the test don't wait the 20 secods, after 2-3 seconds in the modal dialog, it closes, so if anyone can help me, i would really apreciate it

Comment: if there's a close button for the overlay div, click that first.  If not, just use a sleep.  A webdriverwait will only wait until the button is clickable.  (It is, it's just that another element would receive that click.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Get a wait for the element displayed:

ex. WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime("//input[@id='id']");

```
    public static void WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPathTime(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            wait.Until(webDriver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath(value)).Displayed);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
```

Then switch to the popup - In all honesty, this may not even be necessary. Not all popups require you to switch to them.

```
        public static string SwitchToPopup()
    {
        var mainHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var handles = driver.WindowHandles;

        foreach (var handle in handles)
        {
            if (mainHandle == handle)
            {
                continue;
            }
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            break;
        }
        var result = Url;
        return result;
       
    }
```